# No vectors in spacy en in google colab

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, spacy

I am trying to learn to make chatbots in Google Colab.I found that there are no vectors present in spacy 'en'.Whenever I check for the length of vectors using the nlp.vocab.vectors_length it always returns 0.

I have tried running "spacy.cli.download('en')" to install it once again in colab but still the vector length is zero and the shape of vectors is also (0,0)
Here is the code:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')
print(nlp.vocab.vectors_length)
```

The expected output was 300 but it is always 0.Can someone please tell me what's the problem.I am a total beginner to this spacy library and natural language processing.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spaCy's default models do not ship with vectors. You need to download a spaCy model. See: https://spacy.io/usage/models and https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity